# What is the difference between UITextInputDelegate.selectionDidChange and UITextViewDelegate.textViewDidChangeSelection

Tags: uikit, uitextview

Two delegate methods are very similar.

I want to know what's their differences.
When the first will be called, when will another.

`UITextInputDelegate.selectionDidChange`
and
`UITextViewDelegate.textViewDidChangeSelection`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `UITextInputDelegate.selectionDidChange` tells the view which conforms `UITextInput` that the text selection has changed.

While `UITextViewDelegate.textViewDidChangeSelection` tells `UITextView` that the text selection has changed.

In reality `UITextView` conforms the `UITextInput`, so it should not make any difference which method you will be using. But if you implement `UITextInputDelegate` to your textview, it will give you more flexibility to alter selection process e.g `selectionWillChange`, `selectionDidChange`. If you do not this flexibility, stick to `UITextViewDelegate.textViewDidChangeSelection` :)